# LookupAccountName error when ReferencedDomainName is NULL

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, msdn

If I do not save the optional `ReferencedDomainName` in a variable, the function returns `false` and I can no retrieve the used Sid. If the doc says it's optional, why do I need to include that as well? Here is my code:

This works and returns a SID:

```
    DWORD size;
    TCHAR lpAccountName[USERNAME_SIZE];
    PSID Sid = (PSID)LocalAlloc(LPTR, SECURITY_MAX_SID_SIZE);
    LPSTR DomainName = (LPSTR)LocalAlloc(LPTR, sizeof(TCHAR) * 1024);
    DWORD cbSid = SECURITY_MAX_SID_SIZE;
    LPSTR userSIDBuffer = (LPSTR)LocalAlloc(LPTR, sizeof(TCHAR) * cbSid);
    SID_NAME_USE peUse;

    size = USERNAME_SIZE;
    if (!GetUserName(lpAccountName, &size))
    {
        _error("Could not retrieve username.");
    }

    printf("Username found: %s\n", lpAccountName);

    size = 1024;
    if (!LookupAccountName(NULL, lpAccountName, Sid, &cbSid, DomainName, &size, &peUse))
    {
        _error("Could not look up account.");
    }

    return Sid;
```

But If I remove the `DomainName` and change the `size=0` as per MSDN Documentation, I get a 122 error and no `Sid` is returned;

```
        size = 0;
        if (!LookupAccountName(NULL, lpAccountName, Sid, &cbSid, NULL, &size, &peUse))
        {
            _error("Could not look up account.");
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

I can't tell you why they force you to retrieve the domain when you just want the Sid but that is the way the API is designed and there is nothing you can do about it. The domain parameter is optional because the API is designed to be called twice, once to retrieve the required buffer sizes and once to actually fill the buffers.

If you don't like this design you can abstract it away with a helper function:

```
BOOL GetAccountSidFromName(LPCTSTR Account, PSID Sid, const DWORD SidSize)
{
    SID_NAME_USE snu;
    DWORD cbSid = SidSize, cchRD = 0;
    LPTSTR rd = NULL;
    BOOL succ = LookupAccountName(NULL, Account, Sid, &cbSid, rd, &cchRD, &snu);
    if (!succ)
    {
        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
            return FALSE;
        rd = (LPTSTR) LocalAlloc(LPTR, cchRD * sizeof(*rd));
        if (!rd)
        {
            SetLastError(ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY);
            return FALSE;
        }
        cbSid = SidSize;
        succ = LookupAccountName(NULL, Account, Sid, &cbSid, rd, &cchRD, &snu);
        LocalFree(rd);
    }
    return succ;
}

...

TCHAR lpAccountName[USERNAME_SIZE];
DWORD size = USERNAME_SIZE;
if (!GetUserName(lpAccountName, &size))
{
    _error("Could not retrieve username.");
}
BYTE sidbuf[SECURITY_MAX_SID_SIZE];
PSID sid = (PSID) sidbuf;
BOOL success = GetAccountSidFromName(lpAccountName, sid, sizeof(sidbuf));
if (!success)
{
    _error("Could not retrieve sid.");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you supply null instead of `DomainName` function will store required `DomainName` buffer size in `size` and last error will be `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` (122). So to get actual results you must supply `DomainName` buffer of sufficient capacity.

Comment: But I don't want that, I just want the Sid and the documentation says DomainName is optional. Doesn't seem optional if I have to provide it.

Comment: @AlexandruAntochi "optional" means that it is allowed to be null. However it does not mean that function will do the same job in this case. It will only report required buffer size, nothing more.

Comment: @AlexandruAntochi: You don't have to provide the domain name. It's an `Out` parameter. You only have to provide a buffer to receive it. Incidentally, a SID is only meaningful in conjunction with a domain. Whether you want the domain or not doesn't make a difference. SID's are domain-specific.